# Why don't connect gcp slurm vm using ssh?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, slurm

I created a slurm cluster in gcp.

- compute-image
- controller
- login

A total of 3 vm was created, and the number of compute-images fluctuates when executed.

Currently, only the controller VM has an external IP out of the three VMs.

I can't ssh to the slurm vm using vscode on my local computer.

There is no problem with ssh access from that page.

[image]

Other than that vm, normal vm works fine. What's the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to use the VM on your local machine? If yes,could you please provide the name of the VM on which you are not able to SSH (Is it slurm controller or slurm login?) 
If not,could you please follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-slurm-cluster-compute-engine) to deploy slurm cluster in your gcp. I tried this in my environment and I could SSH both slurm controller and slurm login VM’s.
Could you please provide me with some information about [firewallrules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) which are being applied to that particularVM.

Comment: @GoliNikitha The one I was trying to connect to was the controller. As I said in the body, login does not have an external IP.
We have confirmed that the Slurm cluster deployment works normally.
The firewall also opened port 22 in GCP and checked it in the controller.
What's the problem..?

Comment: I have just found a workaround for your issue . Try to SSH into login and use `srun --pty $SHELL` which takes you to SSH page of controller. I followed this [documentation](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp#accessing-compute-nodes-directly) and this works for me, hope it helps you.